# C all the value changes with the pointer

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

I am trying to write a method in C to read from a file.
I don't know how long the file will be but I know the structure.
The problem is that when I change the value of str, all my vars that refer to it are changed. Is there any way for me to keep the value of my vars unchanged? Sorry for the messy code.

```
HashMap read_Table(char* srcfilename){
    FILE* src = fopen(srcfilename, "r");
    if (src == NULL) {
        printf("READ FILE FAILED\n");
    }
    char str[256];
    if (fgets(str, 255, src) != NULL) {
    }
    fgets(str, 255, src);
   char* attribute_size = str;
    int a_size = atoi(attribute_size);
    char **outAttributes = malloc(sizeof(char *) * a_size);
    fgets(str, 255, src);
    for(int i = 0; i<a_size; i++){
        if (fgets(str,255,src) != NULL){
            outAttributes[i] = str;
        }
    }
    fgets(str, 255, src);
    //get key size:
    printf("!!!!!!\n%s", str);
    fgets(str, 255, src);
    //get key size number
    printf("!!!!!!\n%s", str);
    char* key_size = str;
    int k_size = atoi(key_size);
    if (fgets(str, 255, src) != NULL) {
        //get Key:
        printf("!!!!!!\n%s", str);
    }
    char **outKeyItem = malloc(sizeof(char *) * k_size);
    for(int i = 0; i<k_size; i++){
        if (fgets(str,255,src) != NULL){
            printf("!!!!!!\n%s", str);
            outKeyItem[i] = str;
        }
    }
    fgets(str, 255, src);
    //get Table:
    HashMap out_map = new_HashMap((void**)outAttributes, a_size ,(void**)outKeyItem, k_size);
    while (!feof(src)) {
        char** curr_tuple = malloc(sizeof(char *) * a_size);
        for(int i=0;i<a_size;i++){
            if(fgets(str, 255, src)!=NULL){
                curr_tuple[i] = str;
                printf("Tuple: %d %s",i, curr_tuple[i]);
            } else{
                break;
            }
        }
        if(feof(src)){
            break;
        }
        insert(out_map, (void**)curr_tuple);
    }

    printHashMap(out_map);
    printf("\n");
    return out_map;
}
```

Comment: You need to allocate memory to hold the string, and then use `strcpy` to copy the string. There's also a function called `strdup` that is available on some systems.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning pointer instead of copying the contents.

```
        outAttributes[i] = str;
        outKeyItem[i] = str;
```

should be

```
       outAttributes[i] = strdup(str); //basically malloc and strcpy
       outKeyItem[i] = strdup(str);
```

> Note:: `strdup` internally allocates the memory and copies the
>   contents thus you need to `free` once done also `strdup` is not `c`
>   standard.